# Why my lower outliers are not showing in Box plot

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Dataset

```
store id,revenue ,profit
101,779183,281257
101,144829,838451
101,766465,757565
101,353297,261071
101,1615461,275760
101,246731,949229
101,951518,301016
101,444669,430583
```

Code

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
dummies = pd.read_csv('1.csv')
dummies.sort_values(by=['revenue'], inplace=True)
fea = dummies[['storeid']]
lab = dummies[['revenue']]
param = 'revenue'
qv1 = lab[param].quantile(0.25)
qv2 = lab[param].quantile(0.5)
qv3 = lab[param].quantile(0.75)
qv_limit = 1.5 * (qv3 - qv1)
un_outliers_mask = (lab[param] > qv3 + qv_limit) | (lab[param] < qv1 - qv_limit)
un_outliers_data = lab[param][un_outliers_mask]
un_outliers_name = fea[un_outliers_mask]
un_outliers_data
#41      54437
# 44      89269
# 40    1942989
# 6     1951518
dummies.boxplot(by='storeid', column=['revenue'], grid=False)
```

`un_outliers_data` Output is having both outliers higher and lower, But in plot only higher is displayed

My graph is only displaying the higher outliers

[image]

Comment: There's insufficient data to reproduce your results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`un_outliers_data` has the global outliers ie you are considering mean of complete data from `dummies` dataframe. But your box plot filter the data by `storeid` and then calculates median, percentiles etc for this subset of data.

You will see the required outliers (un_outliers_data) if you just do `dummies['revenue'].plot(kind='box')`

Example:
Consider the below small dataset:

`store id,revenue
101, 10
102, 190
103, 200
104, 210
105, 300`

It should be clear that revenue = 10 & 300 are outliers, but they are not outliers if look at the data for store id 101 & 105 respectively.